# Pass Byte Array to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, signalr

I am using SignalR for updating fields on client side using Javascript. I need to pass byte array as an object property. But it doesn't seem to be picking up and shows as either undefined or System.Byte[]. I also tried to create an extra string field in the  object and tried to convert byte array to string and pass it. But both techniques are passing unique or undefined characters. Any suggestions on how to pass data between two sides?

Comment: What did you specify as the content type of your post data?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encode the string. Here's a good JS Base64 encoder/decoder: http://jsbase64.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help! It looks like it could be helpful. Do you have an example for decoding a string?